# Find nearest value in an array in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a number of students, each who are assigned chores on different days of the month.

For example:

```
{ name: 'Josh', choredays: [2, 5, 16, 20, 28]},
{ name: 'Will', choredays: [5, 15, 18, 21, 22]}
```

Given a number, I want to get as output the next day that each student has to do chores.

For example, given `14`, I want to get

```
Josh 16
Will 15
```

How can I express this in Mongo Aggregation?

Comment: Did you mean `Will 15`?

Comment: @FlissHou either that or Will was supposed to do chores on  the 14th.. thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

You need to use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation operator which eliminates the less input values. And then use [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) which eliminates the greater values.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "items": {
      "$filter": {
        "input": "$choredays",
        "as": "chore",
        "cond": { "$gte": [ "$$chore", 14 ] }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$addFields": { "items": { "$slice": [ "$items", 0, 1 ] }}},
  { "$unwind": "$items" },
  { "$project": { "items": 1, "name": 1 }}
])
```

Will give following output

```
[
  {
    "items": 16,
    "name": "Josh"
  },
  {
    "items": 15,
    "name": "Will"
  }
]
```

You can check it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_w_FJaWZK5C)